# I want to get all posts which has more than 250 likes(likes are stored in different tabe)

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have two mysql database table's posts and post_likes...I want to get all posts which has more than 250 likes

right now i am using this query :-

SELECT posts.*, @total_likes := COUNT(nft_likes.id) as total_likes FROM `posts` inner join nft_likes on nft_likes.nft_id=posts.auction_id where @total_likes>1 group by posts.id

This is the first time i have asked a question.so pls forgive for bad way of telling

[post_likes table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRJL5.png)

[post table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKfSR.png)

Comment: Post a sample of your data.

Comment: Read up on aggregate functions here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html,  the HAVING clause - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html , post some code if you get into difficulty.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample data, the expected output corresponding to that data, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for replying...i have added 2 images of table schema

Comment: Please avoid sharing textual data, like the schema of your table, in screenshots. Also, please explain what is not working with the query you've shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `WHERE` clause you can only refer to a row's data. The result of a `COUNT`, however, refers to the aggregation of several rows. Use the `HAVING` clause for limitations on these results.

```
SELECT 
  p.*, 
  COUNT(l.id) AS total_likes
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN nft_likes l ON l.nft_id = p.auction_id 
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(l.id) > 1
ORDER BY p.id;
```